# cannot changed the property of an object inside an array

Tags: data-binding, polymer-1.0, observers

There is a parent element. One of its property is an array of objects. This array is initialised in the ready function. The display of this array is handed down to a child element. What I want to do is to update the quantity of each element in the array whenever the multiplier property changed. I tried to use the override dirty checking technique described in the docs but couldn't get it to work.  I would appreciate some guidance.
    [plunker link][1]

```
[1]: http://plnkr.co/edit/pCZyUC7YtgUU8cpejNpj?p=info
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working example: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/8g5h7p?p=preview)

Few things are corrected, one is this:

```
//DO not use 'this.setItems.0.quantity.value', but:
         this.set('setItems.0.quantity.value', newQuantity);
   console.log("New arr val: ");
   console.log(this.setItems[0].quantity.value);
```

Docs:

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data

https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#array-binding

Comment: That seems to have done the trick. Thanks. Just a note that when the above set statement is enclosed in a for loop, the syntax is `this.set('setItems.'+item+'.quantity.value', newQuantity); instead of this.set('setItems.item.quantity.value', newQuantity);`