# Polymer dom-repeat not rendering changes with function as items

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

In Polymer I'm using a function to compute the items for a `dom-repeat`:

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[first4People(people, people.*)]]">
  <div>
    First: <span>[[item.first]]</span>
    Last: <span>[[item.last]]</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

But no matter what I try I can't get it to render updates when I change a subproperty of `people` (e.g. `people.0.first`). Changes to the array itself work (e.g. `this.push('people', ...)`). Prehaps I'm being hit by the [dirty check](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/model-data#override-dirty-check) in which case I can't figure out how to override it.

Full example:

```
  <body fullbleed unresolved>

    <widget-example></widget-example>

    <dom-module id="widget-example">
        <template>
          <div style="color: red;">Why doesn't rename first person cause a visible change?</div>
          <div>First 4 people:
            <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[first4People(people, people.*)]]">
              <div>
              First: <span>[[item.first]]</span>
              Last: <span>[[item.last]]</span>
              </div>
            </template>
          </div>

          <div>
            <!-- Why doesn't this work? -->
            <button on-tap="renameFirstPerson">Rename first person</button>
            <button on-tap="sendFrontToBack">Send front to back</button>
          </div>
        </template>
        <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "widget-example",
            properties: {
                people: {
                    type: Array,
                    value: () => [
                      {'first': 'Joe', 'last': 'Blogs'}, 
                      {'first': 'Jon', 'last': 'Bigs'}, 
                      {'first': 'John', 'last': 'Doe'}, 
                      {'first': 'Josh', 'last': 'Blo'},
                    ],
                },
            },

            observers: [
              'o(people.*)',
            ],

            o: function(change) {
              console.log('o', change)
            },

            first4People: function() {
              console.log('first4People called');
              return this.people.slice(0, 4);
            },

            renameFirstPerson: function() {
              console.log('before sendFrontToBack', this.people)
              this.set(['people.0.first'], this.people[0].first+'Foo');

            // None of this causes the rename to show up.
              var person = this.people[0];
              this.people[0] = {};
              this.people[0] = person;
              this.notifyPath('people.0');

              this.set('person', {});
              this.set('person', person);

              var people = this.get('people');
              this.set('people', []);
              this.set('people', people);
            },

            sendFrontToBack: function() {
              console.log('before sendFrontToBack', this.people)
              var last = this.shift('people', this.people);
              this.push('people', last);
              console.log('after sendFrontToBack', this.people)
            },
        });
      </script>
    </dom-module>
  </body>
</html>
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yv27I053bk4e3cFbFuhK?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Polymer 1.x this working kind of weird, in 2.0 should be working better but for now you have to empty then rewrite the whole data array to reevaluate the change. For some reason if you do that still nothing happends, but if you give the new value in a new frame then it's start working:

```
// Save the data locally
let peoples = this.people;

// Do the change in the local array
peoples[0].first += 'Foo';

// Empty the data so it can reevaluate 
this.people = []; // this.set('people', []);

// Insert the new data in a new frame     
requestAnimationFrame(time => {
    this.people = peoples; // this.set('people', peoples);
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/cLirT95ot1d5BMFWItwD?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the fix! It is sad that requestAnimationFrame is required :( At least in 2.0 it will be work in a more understandable way.

Answer (score 3):

The specific issue here relates to the use of the computed binding to create an anonymous array for the `items` property. When you change the subproperty using `set`, the computed binding is recomputed, but the `people.0` *object* hasn't changed, so when the `dom-repeat` iterates through the array, dirty checking tells it that the object hasn't changed.

And the `dom-repeat` doesn't know that the change to `people.0.first` is related to its `items` property, so it doesn't get the change that way, either.

One fix it to replace the `people.0` object, like this:

```
renameFirstPerson: function() {
  // create a new object to defeat dirty-check.
  var updated = Object.assign({}, this.people[0]);
  updated.first = updated.first + 'Foo';
  // swap the new object in with 'set', so the observer gets called. 
  this.set('people.0', updated);
}
```

There are some other approaches you could take here, but none of them is super-straightforward. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is correct solution: [Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/5jwY0t?p=preview)

What was misssing is that:

> [Explicit bindings to array items by index isn’t supported](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#array-binding)

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[first4People(people, people.*)]]"> 
    <div>
        Index: <span>[[index]]</span>
        <br>
        First as this:[[arrayItem(people.*, index, 'first')]]
        <br>
        First not as this: <span>[[item.first]]</span>
   </div>
   <br><br>
</template>
```

Simmilar:

[cannot changed the property of an object inside an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40060221/cannot-changed-the-property-of-an-object-inside-an-array/40061703#40061703)

[Polymer, binding to array items not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209556/polymer-binding-to-array-items-not-working/34220464#34220464)

Comment: While that does fix the issue, I think it does so incidentally since `arrayItem(people.*, index, 'first')` depends on the whole `people` list. As far as I understand that link I'm not explicitly binding to an array item. (For example I never write `people.0.first` or `people[0].first`).

Comment: Yes. `item.first` is totally valid inside a `dom-repeat`—accessing array items this way is exactly what `dom-repeat` is designed for. This fixes the problem because `arrayItem()` will be re-evaluated every time `people.*` changes, which is not super efficient.